# What does ActivityMonitor Memory Usage mean?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an application which allocates a large number of objects (mostly of 3 classes) and occasionally releases these.
The ActivityMonitor Real Memory Usage only ever goes up, never down. (Indeed I have noticed this with other applications.)

Profiling shows my application has no leaks, and Garbage Collections shows objects being reclaimed.

Comment: Of the 17 questions (including this) 5 have no answers and 1 I answered myself, hoping to help others with similar issues. I have accepted 6. The other 5 answers did not actually answer the questions, although a couple were helpful, so I upvoted them. Maybe I just ask difficult questions no one can answer. – Milliways 11 mins ago